# How to use command line dpkg options to unpack conf and skip postinst script

Tags: configuration, config, deb, dpkg

I have a need to run `dpkg install`, unpack the `conf` files, but skip running the `postinst` scripts (if it's included in the `deb` file).

I've tried to change the `SHELL` variable to `/usr/bin/true`, but that didn't work. Any other ideas would be great!

Comment: What are your real goals? Just want to get the config-files out of the archive? You could try to make `/bin/sh` a symlink to `/usr/bin/true`. But be careful to not lock yourself out of your system!

Comment: @MartinHöller my goal is to run `apt-get install` without running any `postinit` scripts, if included.

Basically, i have a bunch of packages (built for a different architecture) that i want to install. they won't run on the system that I'm installing them on (different arch issues, etc) so I want to skip running any postinit scripts

Answer (score 7):

According to its man-page `dpkg` doesn't have a command-line-option to disable script execution. However, you can achieve what you want with the following commands (taken from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482928/ignore-apt-get-postinstall-scripts-automatically) from an ubuntu forum):

```
apt-get download <package>
sudo dpkg --unpack <package>*.deb
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.postinst -f
sudo dpkg --configure <package>
sudo apt-get install -yf #To fix dependencies
```

Comment: not really an answer, doesn't acutally use `dpkg` command line options to achieve not running `postinit` scripts